# How to dynamically create Polymer custom element after setting all attributes?

Tags: javascript, polymer

The problem is when I try to create custom element this way

```
var el= document.createElement('my-el');
el.setAttribute('tag-model', "[[myBinding]]");
```

it creates element without its attributes. How to construct custom element with all its attributes and then append to HTML to initilize them?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/polymer-patterns/blob/master/snippets/basics/dynamically-adding-a-custom-element-to-the-dom.html)

It basically says to do it like that:

```
var dynamicEl = document.createElement("my-element");
dynamicEl.setAttribute("id", "my-element-id");
dynamicEl.setAttribute("greeting", "Hello, Good Morning.");
document.body.appendChild(dynamicEl);
```

However, if you want to change properties directly, it wont work with `setAttribute`. You have to do it like that:

```
var dynamicEl = document.createElement("my-element");
dynamicEl.greeting = 'Waaazaaaa???';
document.body.appendChild(dynamicEl);
```