# Iron-pages with dynamically added custom elements

Tags: javascript, polymer

```
<iron-pages attr-for-selected="data-route"
            id="page_router"
            selected="{{selected}}"
            class="b-maillist"
            on-iron-select="_pageSelectHandler"
            selectable="section">
</iron-pages>
```

and when I add kinda `<section data-route="Inbox" id="Inbox">`  elements dynamically I can't select any of them ('iron-selected' class not stamped to element').

How can I add custom elements dynamically in the right way? Thank you!

Comment: you need to make it like said in the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102509/how-to-dynamically-create-polymer-custom-element-after-setting-all-attributes

Comment: I don't think this answer will help. The question is, why dinamically created elements can't be selected within iron-pages element?